# Calculating the orientation of Kinect Sensor using Accelerometer and Elevation Angle

Tags: c#, kinect, accelerometer

Is there a way to use the accelerometer and elevation angle data from a Kinect to determine if the sensor is in an improper physical orientation?  I'm trying to determine if an user has mounted the sensor improperly.

Comment: What is an improper physical orientation? What exactly are you trying to detect?

Comment: Our application uses varying mounting heights and elevation angles. There is a concern that a user could mount the Kinect in a way that would seem correct from the application's point of view, but physically could be extreme or unusual. The only way that I see to make a positive determination of the Kinect's physical orientation is to look at the accelerometer readings and elevation angle.

Comment: The values you get basically form a vector pointing down in world space. That is, if your Kinect is perfectly level, it will point down the Y axis. And if you start tipping it forward, it will start pointing in the Z direction. Based on that you could certainly tell whether or not the mounting is proper.